# trackEvent does not log onclick when injecting javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I'm trying to implement a trackevent into my "rotating ad", however the clicks are not being counted in Analytics.

I'm using a javascript array to house my links, images, and trackevent label.

I am calling the script within the div and inserting my anchor and image within the same DIV.

Here is my script:

```
for (var i=0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
 strCreateLink = "<a href='" + imgArr[position][1] + "' target='_blank' onclick='_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'AdClick', 'Click', '"+ imgArr[position][2] + "']);return false;'><img src='" + imgArr[position][0] + "' /></a>";}
 document.getElementById(ele).innerHTML = strCreateLink;
```

It works when I statically place the elements on the page.  I've also tried placing the onclick on the IMG too.

Any ideas why Google isn't counting these clicks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In this case you just need to fix syntax error with quotes:

```
 onclick='_gaq.push([\"_trackEvent\", \"AdClick\", \"Click\", \""+ imgArr[position][2] + "\"]);return false;'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this for a new Google Analytics profile? If so, are you using Universal Analytics (analytics.js) or the legacy ga.js?

If you're using Universal Analytics, make sure you're using the correct functions as it's relatively new.  Most of the GA documentation on the web is for ga.js.

Comment: Using "legacy" ga.js ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this challenge before. You'll want to make sure analytics has a chance to send the beacon before the default function of the click on the link takes the browser to a new page. The way I resolved it was to create a function to handle outbound links that sends the event beacon and delays proceeding to the clicked `href` by 100ms. You may want to rename this to be more appropriate for your use-case.

```
function trackOutboundLink(link, category, action, label) {
    try {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category , action, label]);
    } catch(err){}

    setTimeout(function() {
        document.location.href = link.href;
    }, 100);
}
```

To call this method `onclick` you must remember to return false. Here's an example:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/"
   onclick="trackOutboundLink(this,
   'Outbound Links', 'google.com',
   'Google Outbound'); return false;">outbound link</a>
```

Without the `return false;`, the browser will follow the `href` immediately. Alternatively, you could trap the event object with the `onclick` to call `event.preventDefault()`, which would have the same effect (and is probably more elegant...).

Comment: I'm going to try these out.  But I also actually solved the issue by using document.getElementById("id").setAttribute("onclick", "trackeventcode");
Not sure why setAttribute worked and not by just writing it into the anchor/div/img.